# display a string in textbox

Tags: c#, string, serial-port

I want to get the data from my serial port and display this data in a textbox. but when i run mu code it displays just one line in the textbox and it gets replaced by the next. but I want the each part of the string under the next one.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    SerialPort serP = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3", 9600, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One);

    while (true)
    {
        serP.Open();
        serP.WriteLine("test");
        string dataIn = serP.ReadLine();
        textBox1.Text = dataIn;             
        serP.Close();
    }
}
```

this is my code, I hope some one can help me out with this.
Rick

Comment: textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + dataIn; try to read about this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate your text:

```
textBox1.Text += dataIn + Environment.NewLine;
```

And make sure your textbox is multiline (`textBox1.Multiline = true` for standart `Windows.Forms.TextBox` or somethimg similar if it's textbox from some controls library)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Andy Korneyev's answer. But if you want each part in a new line you could alter his code like below,

```
textBox1.Text += dataIn + Environment.NewLine;
```

Also if you want to set the textbox as MultiLine in code behind,

```
textBox1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
```

**Note:**
I assume you are working with WinForms. If so, you can also use RichTextBox control. It doesn't need to be set has MultiLine.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` has no property called `TextMode`. It has just `Multiline` boolean property.

Comment: My bad! I wrote the code used for System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pavan. If you want to use more than one line i would prefer RichtTextBox, too.

Also if you only want to display something, you could use a simple label, too.

I think thats much nicer for a user than to have it in a TextBox, but **only** if you want to display something without using it in other things.

Comment: Usage of `RichTextBox` just to display **plain** text instead of setting `textBox.Multiline = true` looks like an "overkill" for me.